# Magento 2: Running any command getting error Class Magento\Webapi\Model\Cache\Type\Web Api\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2, error, server-setup, webapi, command

**Running any command**

**s:up** , **s:di:c** **s:s:d -f** **cache** getting error

> Class Magento\Webapi\Model\Cache\Type\WebApi\Interceptor does not
>   exist

**And like below images, any help will be appreciate.**[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please, check that interceptor class on your server:

```
ls -la generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Model/Cache/Type/Webapi/Interceptor.php
```

(from Magento root dir.)

In case it has a wrong permissions change it according your needs (usually make it accessible by web-server user is enough).

Another case that interceptor class used somewhere in your code directly (or in third-party extensions) but it must not be used directly. Use `grep` on your code directory to check it.

Another case is when file totally missed from the Magento (missed base class `Magento\Webapi\Model\Cache\Type\WebApi`). In that case I'll recommend you to update Magento using composer.

Comment: I just checked **Webapi** folder does not exist in generated/code/Magento/. what can I do now

Comment: @irshad check that your folder has right permissions (so magento can create that file in the future) and because you can’t run setup:di:compile i’ll recommend you to use a hacky way: copy this file from another magento and try to re run setup:di:compile command.

Comment: awesome,   **setup:di:compile**  is running but while running other command **s:up** and **c:c** it shows error  **Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Webapi\Model\Cache\Type\Webapi' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Shopcore/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Model/Cache/Type/Webapi/Interceptor.php on line 7**

Comment: @irshad oh, seems like original class is missed from your system. Try to update while magento using composer.

Comment: on line number 7  , the code is **class Interceptor extends \Magento\Webapi\Model\Cache\Type\Webapi implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface**

Comment: @irshad yes, it means that original class is not accessible and I think it doesn’t exist. When you update magento it will load all required dependencies with that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102103/discussion-between-irshad-and-siarhey-uchukhlebau).

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the DI generated and the Redis too, run these commands to do it:

```
rm -rf generated/*
redis-cli -n 0 flushall
php -r "echo opcache_reset();"
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```